# JavaFX CSS Style Vertical Scrollbar For TreeTableView

Tags: css, javafx

I am currently using CSS to create a dark theme for an application I created. I am having issue creating a dark themed scrollbar, which appears inside a TreeTableView. Most of the scrollbar looks correct, but there is a small extra header created that isn't styled. Here is a picture, of my progress below:

[image]

The TreeTableView is very simple. It has two TreeTableColumns.

My current css relating to the table is below:

```
.tree-table-view
{
    -fx-background-color: #404040;
}

.tree-table-view .scroll-bar
{
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}

.tree-table-view *.column-header-background *.show-hide-columns-button
{
    -fx-background-color: #404040;
}

.tree-table-column
{
    -fx-background-color: #404040;
    -fx-border-color: #2d862d;
    -fx-border-width: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
}

.tree-table-column .label
{
    -fx-border-color: #2d862d;
    -fx-border-insets: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    -fx-border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
}

.tree-table-cell
{
    -fx-text-fill: #e6e6e6;
    -fx-padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
}

.tree-table-row-cell .arrow
{
  -fx-background-color: #2d862d;
}
```

Does anyone know what css class I can use to make the white 'extra header' in the top-left corner have a black background? I would really appreciate it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try style class `.filler` for the `TreeTableView` or `.corner` for the `ScrollBar`

Comment: I just got it to work with .tree-table-view .menu-button as the selector. Thanks for the help jns!

Comment: Ah! I forgot that, because I never show the menu button. Good to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.tree-table-view .filler {
}

Was the selector I needed. Thanks JNS!